# Connect Wind turbine to existing solar inverter with MPPT

Tags: inverter, mppt

Currently I am doing research on connecting a 3.5 kW wind turbine to an existing grid tie solar inverter with MPPT. It would be very nice to use the widely available PV inverters and connect a wind turbine or both solar and a wind turbine to different input channels. I know wind and solar systems are different in a number of ways but I am not yet an expert on this subject. But I was wondering if someone could tell me the flaws and what should be improved.

The generator of the wind turbine will create a three phase AC sine wave that is going to be rectified to DC and filtered. For over Voltages I am planning to use Voltage detection with a breaking circuit in case of over Voltage and to stop the turbine from rotating when the inverter disconnects from the grid.

I am unsure if the MPPT used for solar applications could work for a system like this. I could also add a boost converter to supply a steady Voltage to the inverter if that would help.

I have spoken to an inverter manufacturer and they also have to possibility to turn off the MPPT function for their inverters. So designing a custom MPPT system could also be the way to go perhaps.

Another thought: Do I require a transformer attached to the generator for galvanic isolation?

So my question is, could the proposed system with a wind generator attached to the MPPT of a solar grid tied inverter work? What to improve?

[image: block diagram of system]

Comment: Pick some examples of wind turbines and inverters, then read the spec sheets.

Comment: Your question is too general.  It basically says "can I use any PV MPPT Inverter with any wind turbine."  The answer to that is "NO".  Perhaps you might add some details like the specific make and model of the inverter and the windmill and someone could look at the specs and help you determine compatibility.

Comment: There are inverters designed for wind turbines or dual source; why not consider those instead of forcing the wrong tool to do the job?

Comment: Many, though not all, wind turbines use doubly-fed induction machines for their generators, and those *cannot* be used without a specially designed controller and an external power source. You can't get any power out of them otherwise.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Sorry for being a bit to general. For a research project on University I am tasked to design such a converter for a specific wind turbine.

The problem is also that off the shelve converters for wind are difficult to find for 3.5 kW power

Answer (score 0):

Few of this in parallel will do the job. I also have two of them and I am happy with it.
Regards and good luck.
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32840670989.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.397c24297b9v3n&algo_pvid=28e89ceb-89e4-43d2-8ee3-6861e6a0729f&algo_exp_id=28e89ceb-89e4-43d2-8ee3-6861e6a0729f-25&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000017775982268%22%7D&pdp_pi=-1%3B314.26%3B-1%3B-1%40salePrice%3BEUR%3Bsearch-mainSearch

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).